# Node.JS строки и создание объектов

Tags: node.js

Можно ли создать объект, используя для этого строки или массивы?

Например:

"sgs.hkd=7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6" ---> `var obj= {"sgs": {"hkd": "7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6"}}`.
В ходе выполнения программы можно ли создать объект наполнив его разбитой, как в примере, строкой

Где об этом почитать, или почитать почему так нельзя?

Comment: не понятно в чем заключается вопрос и что должен показывать приведенный пример. Если имелось ввиду прямое соответствие что когда пишешь `sgs.hkd=7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6` это будет равносильно `var obj= {"sgs": {"hkd": "7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6"}}` то так сделать нельзя.

Comment: Да, пояснение у меня получилось крайне сумбурное, прошу прощения.

В ходе выполнения программы можно ли создать объект наполнив его разбитой, как в примере, строкой

Comment: `sgs.hkd=7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6` - это имеется ввиду строка? то есть `"sgs.hkd=7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6"`?

Comment: Да, это строка, скобки поставил. Можно ли наполнить объект этой строкой, разбив на части, что бы вышло +- вот так: var obj= {"sgs": {"hkd": "7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6"}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если формат строки известен, то можно по нему получить список полей и значение и далее свернуть его с помощью метода [`.reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), например с использованием метода [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var obj = str.split(/\.|=/) // получаем список полей, значение будет последним элементом
   .reduceRight((acc,cur)=>({[cur]:acc})); // сворачиваем список в один объект, начиная с последнего элемента.
```

Так же в примере использовано [свойство с вычисляемым именем](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_ECMAScript_2015)

Пример:

```js
var str = "sgs.hkd=7cfsa7b740acd8213a9854348agas49b22b6";
var obj = str.split(/\.|=/) // получаем список полей, значение будет последним элементом
  .reduceRight((acc, cur) => ({
    [cur]: acc
  })); // сворачиваем список в один объект, начиная с последнего элемента.

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Ух ты, первый раз вижу применение reduceRight))